# Outlook automatically change reminder based on category

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to automate Outlook so that when a user sets a certain category on an appointment, it automatically sets the reminder time based on the category.

For example, the user has an "On site meeting" category and an "Off site meeting" category.  He wants the reminder time to automatically change to 15 minutes for an on site meeting and 30 minutes for the off site meeting.  He understands that if he sets the category wrong or applies both categories the time wont change correctly.

Is it possible to do this, and if so how do I go about it?  I imagine there is an event I can catch and handle when an appointment category is changed.

Thank you

EDIT: The appointment requests are received in email, he sets the categories when he accepts the meeting request.  The reminder time should be set whenever the category changes.
How to hook up to the event is the part I can't seem to find.

Comment: By category, do you mean in the Label dropdown (i.e. Vacation, Personal, etc...) or do you mean the "Show Time As" (i.e. Tentative, Busy, Out of Office)?  I believe it's difficult to get the label (vacation or whatever) where the Show Time As is relatively simple...

Comment: By category, he means the "label".  The attribute you get to by right clicking on an appointment and selecting categorize

Answer (score 0):

When exactly is the change of reminder time supposed to happen? When initially composing the meeting? Whenever categories are modified?

(e.g. if the user already set a value for the reminder, and then changed the category, would the reminder change?)

Anyway, I guess the solution is to hook up to some events that happen in Outlook and set these values according to your logic. But until the above questions are answered it's not clear which events you'll need to hook up to.

Answer (score 0):

You will want ItemAdd and ItemChange

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.14).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865866(v=office.14).aspx

Something like this:

```
Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objCalendar = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items
End Sub

Private Sub objCalendar_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    setReminder Item
End Sub

Private Sub objCalendar_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    setReminder Item
End Sub

Sub setReminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    If InStr(Item.Categories, "A")
        ' Set the reminder time A
        GoTo exitRoutine ' A the longer takes priority over B the shorter
    End If

    If InStr(Item.Categories, "B")
        ' Set the reminder time B
    End If

exitRoutine:

End Sub
```