# Remove reminder from incoming email appointment

Tags: vba, outlook

At my work we use emailed appointments to inform everyone that a person is on PTO.  The procedure is to set the reminder to "none" but some forget (we are all human).  I would like to find a way to search the subject of the email for the term "PTO" or "leave early" and set the reminder to "none" if one is set.

I have found a number of questions about find the reminders and even how to change them.  I am getting stuck on the detection part.  I welcome any help.

Here is one of the questions I am using for help.
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667103/outlook-automatically-change-reminder-based-on-category)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on *when* you want this to be checked.  The most likely event to do this is in the [AppointmentItem.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/appointmentitem-send-event-outlook) event.  In order to trap that event, you first must "catch" the new Appointment item as it is created. You can do that by monitoring the Inspectors.NewInspector event and only handle AppointmentItem objects. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/using-outlook-visual-basic-for-applications-to-respond-to-outlook-events) for guidance on working with events in Outlook.

Comment: Actually I am wanting to remove the reminders from ones that other people send when they forget to remove the reminders.

Comment: Reminders that users set on meeting requests are for themselves, not the recipients. They set the reminder on their own calendar when the accept it