# How can I automatically forward an outlook meeting based on the meeting category or when it's marked private?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to automatically forward meetings from my work email to my personal email whenever I flag a meeting as private. I don't really even know where to start. Any one able to help me out?

I've tried looking for solutions based on the category of the meeting but that hasn't yielded any resulted either

Comment: Using *VisualBasic for Applications*, you could add an event handler similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15186513/1911064).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VBA macro where you could handle changes to items by using the [Items.ItemChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemchange) or [AppointmentItem.PropertyChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.propertychange) events. When appointment items marked as private the following property is set under the hood:

```
Appointment.Sensitivity = olPrivate
```

So, you need to track changes made to the [AppointmentItem.Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.sensitivity) property which returns or sets a constant in the `OlSensitivity` enumeration indicating the sensitivity for the Outlook item.

But I'd suggest starting from the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article to be more familiar with VBA environment.